# Command Pattern basics

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern

Suppose I have a file with contents like this, which is a combination of some config information and some commands:

```
server1 192.168.0.1  
server2 192.168.0.12  
file1 /home/user1/file1  
upload file1 to server1  
ping server1  
replicate server1
shutdown server1
```

The command pattern is well-suited to this as each of "upload", "ping", "replicate", and "shutdown" can be represented as a command.

However, I still have a few questions:

**1. Whose responsibility is it to parse the input?**
The input file has necessary information like where the files and servers are. Who will do the parsing? Client? Receiver? Invoker?

**2. Where should the parsed information be stored?**
The parsed information from first 3 lines would go in a `HashMap`. According to [DZone's blog post](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command),

> The Receiver has the knowledge of what to do to carry out the request.

So, I am guessing Receiver is the one where the `HashMap` will stored?

**3. Can commands return results?**
Commands like "ping" or "shutdown" should indicate what happened after the command was executed. Can these commands return values?

Comment: Why do you say, "_The command pattern is well-suited to this_"? Is it simply because the names are stored in a file?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Whose responsibility is it to parse the input?

Each line has 2 parts: command name, and arguments. Arguments are command-specific, so you should have `CommandsProvider` that should:

- Split file to lines
- For each line separate first word and other words
- Create command according to first word (you may have `CommandsRegistry` that knows how to find command by its name)
- Provide all arguments to command

Command `PingCommand` knows its first argument is server. In theory, you may pair each command with `ArgumentsParser` that takes array of words and configures command with it, but not sure it is necessary.

> 2. Where should the parsed information be stored?

Information is stored in command, receiver simply executes it.

> 3. Can commands return results?

Yes, you can implement `execute()` method as you like.

Comment: Ok, the config information can be turned into a `ConfigureCommand` and the result can be stored in a `HashMap`. Every command will then access this `HashMap`? Or should a command only have access to what it needs, rather than the entire `HashMap`?

Comment: Command should have access to only its own data: ``new PingCommand(restPartOfLine)`` restPartOfLine here is ["server1", "192.168.0.1"]. Only ``PingCommand`` knows how to deal with it